# Is there a post that compares major proof assistants?

Tags: discussion

Is there a post that compares major Proof Assistants and provides suggestions of when to use each one, e.g. comparing: Agda, Coq, Idris, Isabelle, and Lean? With suggestions

If not, can create a post?